# Displayed haystack search result in template using result.field_name shows within square brackets issue

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm able to display the search result using django haystack with solr as back end. But the issue is that the displayed values that has been indexed by search engine is been got displayed within the square brackets as in json eg : ['User name']. How to display this properly?

search_indexes.py

```
class ShowcaseSearch(indexes.SearchIndex,indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True,use_template=True)
    showcase_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='showcase_name')
    created_date= indexes.CharField(model_attr='created_date')
    status = indexes.CharField(model_attr='status')
    created_by = indexes.CharField(model_attr='created_by')


    def get_model(self):
        return Showcase    
    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        qs=self.get_model().objects.exclude(status='P')\
       .filter(is_active='Y')
        return qs
```

showcase_text.txt

```
 {{object.showcase_name|safe}}
 {{object.created_date|safe}}
 {{object.reg_id.reg_name|safe}}
```

search.html

```
{% for result in object_list %}
   <tr>
     <td><a href="{% url 'showcase:showcase_applicant_view' 
     pk=result.object.id %}">{{result.showcase_name}}</a></td>
     <td>{{result.created_date}}</td>
     <td>{{result.created_by}}</td>                                
  </tr>
 {% empty %}
   <p>No results found.</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

Resulting slor index file

```
{
    "id":"showcase.showcase.31",
    "django_ct":["showcase.showcase"],
    "django_id":[31],
    "text":["Test 52\nJuly 19, 2019, 6:58 p.m.\nInvestor"],
    "showcase_name":["Test 52"],
    "created_date":["2019-07-19T13:28:36.710Z"],
    "status":["N"],
    "created_by":["test_tt@abc.in"],
    "_version_":1640491605421981702},
```

I expect the result.showcase_name should display corresponding name Test 52, but instead it is displayed with in square brackets like ['Test 52'].
Also please let me know how to get showcase id from text field of solr file, instead of retrieving from model instance using result.object.id.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` indicates that the field is an array (i.e. multivalued in Solr). If you're not using a schema, that will be the default value for any fields created.

You can access the first element in the array returned for `showcase_name` by referring directly to it:

```
{{ result.showcase_name[0] }}
```

.. or you can create an explicit schema in Solr. Remember to empty your index and reindex afterwards in that case.

Comment: I got this template errror, django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'result.created_date[0]'.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the syntax for Django templates (and not pure Jinja2 templates) is `{{ result.created_date.0 }}` iirc.

Comment: Still dint work out. Its just get the first letter from the array, like  result.created_date.0   gives [,  only.. Is there any other way?? Thanks

Comment: That seems to indicate that you have a _string_ containing `[]` when its accessed by the template. Start by outputting (with `pprint.pprint` for example) the content returned by `index_queryset` and look at the properties, then in each stage before the template accesses it.

Comment: Thanks Mat, am new to haystack and django, so didnt know much. In examples everyone gets the results by simply mentioning result.field_name, can you please tell me what's wrong in my code. As you can see in the solr index file data is represent as i mentioned previously. Is any other way to get proper results.